# Alternative word to "お[巡]{まわ}りさん"?

Tags: word-choice

I do not like the word "お巡りさん" because it sounds おこちゃま. I doubt an adult would say such a word.

- What is an alternative word to say for "お巡りさん"?
- In daily conversation, can I say 警察者{けいさつしゃ} instead of "お巡りさん"?
- In daily conversation, can I say 警察官{けいさつかん} instead of "お巡りさん"?

Comment: @naruto yes. I asked a duplicate. Sorry that I did not do a search.

Comment: I don't think お巡りさん is "おこちゃま", like 魚屋さん isn't ”おこちゃま".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use 警官.  I think this is very common to use.  You could also use 刑事（さん）, but this specifically means "detective", so it's not usable for every type of patrolman that you see.